# Is it possible to add a timeout in try block in python

Tags: python, try-except

I am trying to download a URL using python-wget downloaded from :
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wget

This package does not support a timeout option, hence it takes some time (around 10seconds) roughly for a query to fail. Is it possible to add a timeout in our try block to lessen the wait time for a function.

Something like this:

```
try(timeout=5s):
     wget.download(URL)
except:
    print "Query timed out"
```

Comment: It is not possible. Make sure that `download` function accepts timeout, or use multi-threads.

Comment: No but, if all you want is a timeout, there are other ways: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way (i.e. if `download` doesn't support timeout and you can't modify the code) to achieve that is by running the code in another thread:

```
from threading import Thread

t = Thread(target=wget.download, args=(URL,))
t.daemon = True
t.start()
t.join(5)
if t.is_alive():
    print 'Timeout'
```

Comment: Wouldn't the code above require a continuous loop after the wget.download to check whether or not it had timed out?

Comment: @brianlmerritt sure.